# How can I add a custom javascript to the cms mediawiki-1.34.0?

Tags: mediawiki

I need add a custom javascript (bootstrap.js, for example) to the cms mediawiki-1.34.0.
I found a way related to downloading the script file and add string

```
mw.loader.load ('/w/index.php?title=MediaWiki:bootstrap.js&action=raw&ctype=text/javascript');
```

in
    http://localhost/WikiRobotNET/index.php/MediaWiki:Common.js

However, this method does not suit me. Is it possible to hook up a script directly in the code? How to do it?

Comment: I found answer. https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Snippets/Load_an_additional_JavaScript_or_stylesheet_file_on_all_pages

And https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29902768/how-to-add-custom-global-javascript-to-mediawiki/29903953 (Answer by Ilmari Karonen).